# How to determine if system Ax = b has a solution for all choices of b?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I'm supposed to determine if system Ax = b (where x and b have appropriate number of components) has a solution for all choices of b.

For example, for these matrices:

a)$$A=\left( \begin{array}{c} 3 & -4 \\ 4 & 2 \end{array}\right)$$

b)$$A=\left( \begin{array}{c} -3 & 2 & 1 \\ 1 & -1 & -1 \\ 5 & -4 & -3\end{array}\right)$$

In my textbook, I'm only given the answer, but not the steps on how the answer came about.

a) For every choice of b there is a solution of Ax + b

b) There is a choice of b where there is no solution to Ax = b

I've used Gaussian elimination on the matrix, but I'm not sure what to do from there.

Also, how do you determine if columns of a given matrix spans R^3?

Given this matrix:

$$\left( \begin{array}{c} 2 & 1 & -3 & 5 \\ 1 & 4 & 2 & 6 \\ 0 & 3 & 3 & 3\end{array}\right)$$

I've reduced it to 
$$\left( \begin{array}{c} 1 & 4 & 2 & 6 \\ 0 & -7 & -7 & -7 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\end{array}\right)$$

All I know is that if 0 = 0, there are infinitely many solutions and if 0 equals a non-zero, then the system has no solutions.

Since the bottom row of the matrix is all zero, wouldn't the columns span R^3? However, the answer in the textbook is that the columns do not span R^3.
Not sure if it's a typo or I'm just not getting it. Probably the latter!

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

If $Ax=0$ has only the trivial solution $x=0$, then $Ax=b$ has a solution for every $b$.

For that check determinant of the matrix in question. If it's not zero, the equation has a solution for every b, otherwise it's not guaranteed.

Comment: Why?$\,\,\,\,\,$

Comment: @AliceRyhl if the only solution is the zero solution, then the vectors are linearly independent (they are vectors that point in different directions), and you could get to any point (b) with linear combinations of these vectors (they span the entire space), or in other words, "Ax=b  has a solution for every b"

Answer (score 1):

$A$ has to be *non-singular* and $b$ has to lie in column space of $A$ for the system $Ax=b$ to have a solution.

To determine if the columns of a given matrix spans $R^3$, check if the column vectors of the matrix are independent. Independence implies that the column vectors span the $R^n$ space.

> Since the bottom row of the matrix is all zero, wouldn't the columns span $R^3$

No. Since you have only two independent row vectors that can span only a 2-dimensional subspace.